# UWP Map Control crashes since 2020/11/16

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml, uwp-maps

Starting yesterday, the `MapControl` crashes when zooming around with a `Win32Exception` that cannot be handled by the debugger.

```
Faulting application name: MapCrash.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5e58842a
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.19041.546, time stamp: 0x73123758
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x0009edbb
Faulting process id: 0x31f0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6bcd94691205c
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
```

`0xc0000409` seems to be a stack corruption (`STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN`). The following, minimal sample will reproduce the issue:

```
<Page
    x:Class="MapCrash.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps">

    <Grid>
        <maps:MapControl x:Name="Map"></maps:MapControl>
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

This crash poped up yesterday with no code changes and can be reproduced with all SDK versions on Windows 10 1909 and 2004 (on a lot of different client machines).

Did anyone already encounter and overcome this issue?

Comment: You'll likely have more luck posting an issue to https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues

Comment: I doubt that, because it is an UWP issue, not a WPF one. If you know the Microsoft forums, you know that you will not get any help there. Nevertheless, the map does not crash if there is no internet connectivity, so this seems to be caused by Microsoft's servers.

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/1259

Comment: Glad you found the answer @Gene - sorry I pointed you in the wrong direction - for some reason my brain conflates "UWP" and "WPF".

Comment: @IanKemp no worries. Unfortunately there is no resolution yet, but I will post an answer as soon as there is one.

Comment: @Gene I have the same issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870089/uwp-mapcontrol-crashes-after-zooming-in

Comment: @MosheGutman thanks for the link, will mark this one as a duplicate. Interesting how the votes differ on both questions :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been mitigated by Microsoft. Details can be found in the Microsoft forums https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=bingmapswindows8

There was an issue with a tiling service the UWP control uses and a change to that service was rolled back to mitigate the issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When writing an answer, you may want to explain why you think your answer is correct, as it may be the case it is not targeting exactly the same problem and the explanation may help to see why

Comment: @bamishr probably because she is working at Microsoft and was communicating with the responsible team? :)